# grails Spring Security how to get the actual and singular authority of user

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is there a method for Spring Security that returns only the singular authority in the user's row?
Things like this...

```
springSecurityService.principal
def authorities = principal.authorities

 SpringSecurityUtils.getAuthorities()
```

returns *every* role below the user's role as well.

Also the authority collection comes back unsorted by permission level-otherwise I could treat the first (or last) one as the one I want.
Can I sort the authorities?

Comment: What is the 'singular' authority by your definition?  As you said, users have multiple roles - there's nothing to indicate any precedence of any of those roles.  Technically you could add an isSingular property to the UserRole object and manage that yourself, but I'm not clear on the problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: the roles have a heirarchy by sortorder. A user is assigned a role, and they have access to all roles under them. By singular I mean the highest authority. By the time spring security utils loks at them, they are just strings in no particular order, so I can't figure out a way to dynamically find the highest one.